# How to use link_to in rails to put multiple things in a single link?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is my code:

```
 <div class="column">
     <div class="post-module">
          <a href="https://www.livescience.com/59802-should-we-fear-
               intelligent-robots.html" >
          <div class="thumbnail">
              <div class="date">
                  <div class="day">14</div>
                  <div class="month">Jul</div>
              </div>
              <img src="#"/>
          </div>
          <div class="post-content">
              <div class="category">Robots</div>
              <h1 class="title">Should We Fear The Rise of Intelligent 
               Robots? </h1>
              <h2 class="sub_title"> Robots will unite. </h2>
              <p class="description"></p>
          </div> 
        </a>       
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to make that code in rails but I am just a beginner in rails and I wasn't able to find something that could help me in this. I only know the basic idea of the link_to in rails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`link_to`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to)  method can take a block and display it's evaluation as a link content:

```
<%= link_to "https://www.livescience.com/59802-should-we-fear-intelligent-
  robots.html" do %>
   <div class="thumbnail">
     <div class="date">
         <div class="day">14</div>
             <div class="month">Jul</div>
                 </div><img src="#"/>
             </div>
             <div class="post-content">
                 <div class="category">Robots</div>
                 <h1 class="title">Should We Fear The Rise of 
                 Intelligent Robots? </h1>
                 <h2 class="sub_title"> Robots will unite. </h2>
                 <p class="description"></p>
             </div> 
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks ! One more question, please. If the link is one I made and it's in my local pc, for example, I have a page called robotics.html.erb I want to link to. Do I link it like robotics_path ??

Comment: Yea, you can provide any url. But make sure that you have `robotics_path` helper: `rake routes` lists all the routes (with urls and helpers) defined in the application.